# Не приходят данные POST-запросом ReactJS

Tags: php, ajax, reactjs, http, axios

Отправляю POST-запрос:

```
axios({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/parser/api/get_stake_result.php',
    data: {
        id_market: bet.id_market,
        id_outcome: bet.id_outcome,
        stake: this.state.value
    }
})
```

Через инструменты разработчика увидел, что данные отправились на сервер, но на сервере супер-глобальный массив `$_REQUEST` (и соответственно `$_POST`) пустые:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *');

var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте получить данные вот так

```
$data = json_decode(trim(file_get_contents('php://input')), true);
$id_market = $data->id_market;
$id_outcome = $data->id_outcome;
$stake = $data->stake;
```